# Native incoming call is killing my VOIP app's access to audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, voip

I'm developing a VOIP app that allows people to make VOIP calls. Whenever a user is in a VOIP call and receives a native call on their phone the audio of the VOIP app stops working.

I've read that one must reinitialize the AudioSession and I'm doing so with this block of code but this is not working. Any suggestions?

```
self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
[self handleCall];

- (void)handleCall
{
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    self.callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall *call){

    if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateConnected])
    {
    }
    else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDialing])
    {
    }
    else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDisconnected])
    {
      NSLog(@"Call ended");
       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [session setActive:YES error:nil];
       });
    }
    else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateIncoming])
    {
      NSLog(@"Call received");
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on VoIP App with SIP library using. If you are also using same library, while getting native call if your VoIP call already existed, then native call terminate your VoIP call audio session. So, while getting native call, just make "Mute" your SIP library and after ended the native call, just "UnMute" thats it.

```
    pjsua_conf_adjust_rx_level(0 /* pjsua_conf_port_id slot*/, 0.0f); //for mute the audio

    pjsua_conf_adjust_rx_level(0 /* pjsua_conf_port_id slot*/, 1.0f); //for unmute the audio.
```

I hope this will help you.